# _FILES['file1']['tmp_name'] is empty when tried to upload file in php

Tags: php

This problem occurs since few days ago.  This script is going well on localhost and on another online server. Hoping for response. I am unable to upload file on server.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div align="center">
    <div style="border:solid;">
<form action="test-upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="f1" id="f1" onSubmit="return cb1();">  
<div align="left" class="contentrequire"><strong>Attach Excel File (Call Detail/Description) </strong></div>
    <label>
       <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1" />
            </label>
            <label>
            <input type="submit" name="save" id="save" />
            </label>
        </form>
      </div>
</div>

 <?php 
    if(isset($_POST['save']))
    {

        echo print_r($_FILES);
        ?>
        <?php 


    //$target_path = $target_path ."testpankaj".".".$ext;


        echo $_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'];
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'], "images/" . $_FILES["file1"]['name'])) {
           echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['file1']['name']). 
        " has been uploaded";
        } else{
            echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: whats your file size you trying to upload? You can check your `MAX_FILE_SIZE ` in `php.ini` file.

Comment: max file size in php.ini is = 8M and my upload file size is 200 KB

Comment: onSubmit="return cb1();" what is that, you ar trying to uplaod via javascript ?

Comment: no it was for validating form email. You can remove it.

Comment: It seems, I can not get any solution of this problem.

Comment: don't use echo for debugging, use var_dump, what do you get from `var_dump($_FILES);` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['save']))
```

That's the issue, I believe. The input doesn't appear to be defined. Just add it, like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="save" id="save" value="sent" />
```